# 500 Internal Server Error on CSV Import w/ Large Photos

Tags: php, csv, prestashop-1.6

I am having trouble with importing products with a CSV file.

I am trying to upload a CSV file with about 1400 products. . . most with three pictures or so. .. .  but the pictures are quite large at 3-4 megabytes.  So far, while testing,  I have only tried importing from a CSV file with 5 items.

I originally was getting an error within prestashop indicating the pictures for my products could not be copied.   The products were imported but just did not have the photos.  I researched this and found that the PHP.INI file needed to be updated.  I have done this with the following parameters:

```
<?php
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

memory_limit = 256M
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_vars = 3000;
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000;
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000;


?>
```

My PHP info file is here:  www.gbamedical.com/info.php

Now I get a 500 Internal Server Error.  The actual error in the error log is the following:

> [Tue Jul 22 23:21:19 2014] [5435820] [fcgid:warn] [client 97.115.27.65:60638] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds, referer http://www.gbamedical.com/shoppe/05ad01min05/index.php?controller=AdminImport&token=62fefdea84f98bf2f436dafc040b6c1f
>
> [Tue Jul 22 23:21:19 2014] [5435820] [core:error] [client 97.115.27.65:60638] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer http://www.gbamedical.com/shoppe/05ad01min05/index.php?controller=AdminImport&token=62fefdea84f98bf2f436dafc040b6c1f

What am I doing wrong?  I have experimented with smaller pictures and it works but the vendor's data feed I am using does not have smaller pictures for the 1400 items and it is a MONSTER job to make them smaller.

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

Trevor

Comment: how are the images stored in a csv? i expect a csv to only contian text

Comment: @Dagon you include an url for the image as a field of the csv: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/CSV+Import+Parameters

Comment: @Dagon yea. . . sorry . . . I should have clarified.  The CSV file points to an URL for the images for each product.

Comment: @rsanchez  Any ideas on how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

For your testing environment, add the images to a locally served url and update your csv to reflect that change

```
http://localhost/importimages/image_name.jpg
```

then do something similar for your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was that [set_time_limit(0)](http://php.net/set_time_limit) would fix this, but stream operations are not counted in the execution time (unless on windows), so depending how you are downloading the files from prestashop, it might not actually count in execution time (I guess fopen() wouldn't).

Apparently, this is a fcgid specific issue. You need to (depending on your version) add this to you fcgid.conf:

```
FcgidIOTimeout 180
```

It used to be IPCCommTimeout. The value is in seconds (the manual is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout)). Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

look at this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/80929/disable-the-timeouts-on-apache-httpd-and-fastcgi

The argument you need to pass to the fastcgi process is: `-idle-timeout 360`

You can adjust the value (here:360) to suit your needs

Adjust `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf`. Append the previous stated argument to the `FastCgiExternalServer`.

My config:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
   AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
   Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
   Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 360
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

This should let your apache wait longer for the fastcgi process to complete. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I use Centos 6 and fcgi. I set in /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

```
MaxRequestLen 1073741824
FcgidBusyTimeout 6000
```

And when I import csv my importing process work as background process